# RoR: How do I count hits to specific links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter

I'm newbie in Ruby on Rails

I want to count hits to specific links, store count in database, and it will be great if it'll count only unique links.

Is there any gem or something?

Comment: don't invent the wheel, there's an excellent tool for checking unique visitors called google analytics: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Comment: I want to output hits from db, it is kinda download counter but for something different.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your ApplicationController (`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`):

```
before_filter :count_hits
def count_hits
  # This tries to find a existing PageHit by the given url. If it does
  # not find one, it creates one.
  @hit = PageHit.find_or_create_by_url(request.url)

  # Issues an UPDATE page_hits WHERE id = 123 SET count = count + 1
  # on the underlying database layer. This atomically increments, so
  # you do not run into race conditions.
  PageHit.increment_counter(:count, @hit.id)
end
```

Make sure you create a `PageHit` model, containing an url string and a count integer.

Comment: 'increment!' is not in fact atomic. Check the generated SQL- it does a select followed by an update. You want the ActiveRecord static method 'increment_counter'.

Comment: This is still vulnerable to with either duplicate url records (if you have no unique constraint) or ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exceptions if you do have it. This is a tough problem to solve. :-( My attempt at asking a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387022/atomic-insert-or-increment-in-activerecord-rails