# atomic insert or increment in ActiveRecord/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

What's the best way to implement an atomic insert/update for a model with a counter in Rails? A good analogy for the problem I'm trying to solve is a "like" counter with two fields:

```
url   : string
count : integer
```

Upon insert, if there is not currently a record with a matching url, a new record should be created with count 1; else the existing record's `count` field should be incremented.

Initially I tried code like the following:

```
Like.find_or_create_by_url("http://example.com").increment!(:count)
```

But unsurprisingly, the resulting SQL shows that the `SELECT` happens outside the `UPDATE` transaction:

```
Like Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `likes`.* FROM `likes` WHERE `likes`.`url` = 'http://example.com' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  UPDATE `likes` SET `count` = 4, `updated_at` = '2013-01-17 19:41:22' WHERE `likes`.`id` = 2
(1.6ms)  COMMIT
```

Is there a Rails idiom for dealing with this, or do I need to implement this at the SQL level (and thus lose some portability)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of any ActiveRecord method that implemts atomic increments *in a single query*. Your own answer is a far as you can get.

So your problem may not be solvable using ActiveRecord. Remember: ActiveRecord is just a mapper to simplify some things, while complicating others. Some problems just solvable by plain SQL queries to the database. You will loose some portability. The example below will work in MySQL, but as far as I know, not on SQLlite and others.

```
 quoted_url = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(@your_url_here)
::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO likes SET `count` = 1, url = \"#{quoted_url}\" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count+1;");
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of your solution (quoted_url is quoted twice). This ended up being about 5x faster than catching ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique. Seems like something Rails ought to provide.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html),

```
like = Like.find_or_create_by_url("http://example.com")
like.with_lock do
    like.increment!(:count)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I have come up with so far. This assumes a unique index on the `url` column.

```
begin
  Like.create(url: url, count: 1)
  puts "inserted"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  id = Like.where("url = ?", url).first.id
  Like.increment_counter(:count, id)
  puts "incremented"
end
```

Rails' `increment_counter` method is atomic, and translates to SQL like the following:

```
UPDATE 'likes' SET 'count' = COALESCE('count', 0) + 1 WHERE 'likes'.'id' = 1
```

Catching an exception to implement normal business logic seems rather ugly, so I would appreciate suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Rails supports [Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), if that's what you're looking for, so:

```
Like.transaction do
  Like.find_or_create_by_url("http://example.com").increment!(:count)
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that by itself won't work. If you don't have a unique index on the url column, it's possible to get get duplicate inserts. If you do have a unique index, you'll get ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique. I just tested both scenarios by adding a "sleep 5" in the transaction block. I think a DB isolation level of SERIALIZABLE would be required to make this work as-is.

Comment: Transactions don't help in cases like this because they make sure a set of changes succeeds or fails, but don't stop somebody in a different thread or process (Specifically in a different database connection in rails) from doing the same change. The correct answer is to use a row lock to prevent other threads from changing the same row you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution thus far:

```
Like.increment_counter(
  :count, 
  Like.where(url: url).first_or_create!.id
)
```

Answer (score -2):

For this use case and others, I think `update_all` [approach](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/activerecord-atomic-check-and-update-through-optimistic-locking/) is cleanest.

```
num_updated =
  ModelClass.where(:id             => my_active_record_model.id,
                   :service_status => "queued").
             update_all(:service_status => "in_progress")
if num_updated > 0
  # we updated
else
  # something else updated in the interim
end
```

Not exactly you example, just pasted from the linked page. But you control the `where` condition and what is to be updated. Very nifty