# GitLab: Is the backup rake task atomic?

Tags: gitlab

If I make a GitLab backup using the [gitlab:backup:create](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) rake task just as someone is pushing to the repositories, will the backup process be affected?

Is it necessary to shutdown GitLab before doing the backup?

Comment: Sorry for the closing votes: the moderators are usually doing a wonderful job, but in this instance, they are simply wrong (and have no idea what gitlab is). This is 100% a question on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The very latest commits from GitLab show more atomic operations now. See my edited answer.

Comment: At a glance, this question definitely looks off-topic or poorly worded, but actually reading through it (and the gitlab tag summary), it does seem perfectly on topic. It's a developer tool and the use thereof. Adding a reopen vote.

Answer (score 5):

The task [`gitlab/backup.rake`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake) itself doesn't look atomic.
It calls:

```
  Rake::Task["gitlab:backup:db:create"].invoke
  Rake::Task["gitlab:backup:repo:create"].invoke
```

[That uses](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake#L172-L192) the [gem `activerecord`](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord):

```
    puts "Dumping database tables ... ".blue
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |tbl|
    ...
```

Like other operations with ActiveRecord (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387022/atomic-insert-or-increment-in-activerecord-rails)), it doesn't seem to be a global atomic operation.

---

Hold on, a few hours ago, [randx (Dmitriy Zaporozhets)](https://github.com/randx), main developer for GitLab, just refactored the dumping a database:

- [commit 38d23c0e5f816937047c9326f9dd33fb10490032](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/38d23c0e5f816937047c9326f9dd33fb10490032) shows the use of the system call `mysqldump`:
  `system("mysqldump #{mysql_args} #{config['database']} > #{db_file_name}")`
- [commit c33d5e16fe5f5dde4f270adaf7fb6fe5b9552018](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/c33d5e16fe5f5dde4f270adaf7fb6fe5b9552018) add `GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, ...`

So the part dumping the database is now more atomic ;)
But the backup itself, which involves other steps including backing up the bare repos, is not atomic.

Comment: The repos themselves are backed up using `git bundle`, so they should be safe as well. Uploads are simple files and write-once, so there should be no issues there either. The database might not be perfectly in sync with repos and files, but not in a way that should cause data loss. All in all, it looks entirely safe to do a backup while GitLab is running, even if it's not atomic.

Comment: @SørenLøvborg I agree.