# How to make a consistent gitlab backup?

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab has a [backup task](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) that generates a backup of the entire system. It seems to get the job done, but looking at other questions here in stack exchange, it doesn't feel safe, specially in busy systems.

In particular, it seems that the task [may create a inconsistent backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825735/gitlab-is-the-backup-rake-task-atomic). Considering that it seems to dump the database first and only then make a dump of each repository, it is very likely that a commit could be made between the database dump and the repository dump.

So my two questions are:

1. What happens if a commit is made after the database dump and how does it affect the restore process?
2. What is the best way of making a consistent backup of all data? Maybe using LVM snapshots?

Comment: If the DB backup is atomic, and the git repo backup is _also_ atomic, but something is committed in-between the two, what happens? The git backup must still contain everything the DB backup refers to, right? So is that inconsistent in any problematic sense?

Comment: Yes, but won't the DB be missing a commit if it only exists in the git repo? Won't it cause a problem when I start making new commits on this repository?