# Are MySQL InnoDB transactions serializable/atomic?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concurrency, innodb

I am confused whether or not MySQL transactions are serializable and whether or not read-anomalies are guarded against?

For example, what if I `SELECT` a value from a row, then `UPDATE` that row by incrementing the value. There is an opportunity for another query to `UPDATE` the row which is being read, leading to an improper update.

However, I was under the impression that even if I wrap these two statements in a transaction, that I am not guaranteed to be free of race conditions. See [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387022/atomic-insert-or-increment-in-activerecord-rails). So to prevent this I used `UPDATE` with `COALESCE` which is a single query and thus guaranteed to be atomic. Was this assumption correct? Or would a transaction have worked here to guarantee no race conditions?

I see from the [MySQL 5.7 documentation  on isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) that transactions are by default `REPEATABLE_READ` rather than `SERIALIZABLE`. What if I had set the transaction level to `SERIALIZABLE`? I attempted to read the documentation on `REPEATABLE_READ` but it did not increase my understanding with regards to this issue.

Comment: Pls read all answers in the duplicate topic. All of them approach the wuestion from slightly different angle.

Comment: `BEGIN; SELECT ... FOR UPDATE; UPDATE ...; COMMIT;`